# How to pass a type to generic method in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin, parameter-passing, generic-type-argument

I have a generic method like below

```
private fun <T> getSomething(): T {
    return "something" as T
}
```

How can I call this method with a variable `T` type?

```
val types = arrayListOf<Type>(String::class.java, Boolean::class.java)
types.forEach { type ->
    val something = getSomething<type>() // Unresolved reference: type
}
```

At runtime, I don't know what would be generic type `T`. I am getting the type from `types` and should pass it with generic `getSomething` method.

#### Use case

I want to call database which has several table. Example models are like this

```
class User{

}

class Student{

}
```

Since all the calling queries are basically same, I want to have generic method for calling database and get data.

```
private fun <T> getData(model: String): List<T>?{
    return when(model){
        "user" -> getUsers()
        "student" -> getStudents()
        else -> null
    }
}
```

So when I call above method. Within my loop I want to pass `Type` as either `User` or `Student`.

```
val types = arrayListOf<Type>(User::class.java, Student::class.java)
types.forEach { type ->
    val data = getData<type>(type.javaClass.simpleName) // Unresolved reference: type in <type>
}
```

How can I achieve it.

Comment: from your above example, You are not passing the type instead you are returning the type.
What actually you want ??

Comment: Why do you want to call it with a "variable class name"? What do you want to do with that? Since generics can only be used for static type checking, and a variable is by definition not static, there is nothing that you could do with a variable generic type. (The one exception is a `reified` generic type on an inline function, but you're not using that)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It doesn't have to be "variable class name". I edited the example a bit. So I have the class list and I have to pass the type it from there to `getSomething` method. If it's possible with `reified` how can I do with it?

Comment: What do you want to do with this? What do you want to do with `something` that requires this feature? Please show that in your code.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I included an example which I hope explains what I want to do

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Here's a complete example:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

data class User(val name: String)
data class Student(val name: String)

fun getUsers(): List<User> = listOf(User("JB"))
fun getStudents(): List<Student> = listOf(Student("Claire"))

fun <T: Any> getData(clazz: KClass<T>): List<T>? {
    return when(clazz) {
        User::class -> getUsers() as List<T>
        Student::class -> getStudents()  as List<T>
        else -> null
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val types = listOf(User::class, Student::class)
    types.forEach { type ->
        val data = getData(type)
        println(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: then you will have your val data as List<Any>, and will have to guess what type it has to be cast to for further usage. 
So what's the point?

Comment: That's something you should ask the OP, not me. But you will only have that in such a loop, where you want to do the same thing whatever the type is. If you know the type, and use getData(Student::class), you'll get a List<Student>, not a List<Any>.

Comment: I checked it in Idea - in your case, val data is List<Any?>

Comment: No, it's List<Any>?. So what? As I said, here you want to do the same thing whatever the type is, and you don't know the actual type. If you do, and use `val data = getData(Student::class)`, you get a List<Student>?.

Comment: > use val data = getData(Student::class), you get a List<Student>?

Yes, you're right
But if you know the type and set it explicitly, how it's different from direct call call "getStudents"?

Comment: I have a similar problem here [Modularising to create a function with variable Types in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66961161/modularising-to-create-a-function-with-variable-types-in-kotlin). Can you please help.

Comment: Hmm ... I have same kind of problem with a database, with same kind tables with same kind data types. Problem here is with getUsers and getStudents methods, that are same kind and benefit with code is make those methods generic with a type. This solution does not help with that problem, but code is more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

I would stick to concrete types like

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

interface IBaseData
interface IDataTable<out T> where T : IBaseData
{
    fun getData(): List<T>
}

class User : IBaseData
class Student : IBaseData

class UserTable : IDataTable<User>
{
    override fun getData(): List<User>
    {
        return listOf(User())
    }
}

class StudentTable : IDataTable<Student>
{
    override fun getData(): List<Student>
    {
        return listOf(Student())
    }
}

inline fun <reified T: IBaseData> getDataTable() : IDataTable<T>?
{
    return when(T::class)
    {
        User::class -> UserTable() as IDataTable<T>
        Student::class -> StudentTable() as IDataTable<T>
        else -> null
    }
}

fun main()
{
    var user = getDataTable<User>()?.getData()
    var student = getDataTable<Student>()?.getData()
}
```

But still, it's an overhead, why not to use `getUser()` or `getStudents()` directly

Comment: I have a similar problem here [Modularising to create a function with variable Types in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66961161/modularising-to-create-a-function-with-variable-types-in-kotlin). Can you please help.

Comment: Hmm ... I have same kind of problem with a database, with same kind tables with same kind data types. Problem here is with getUsers and getStudents methods, that are same kind and benefit with code is make those methods generic with a type. This solutions has same problem as above one, we still need to write separate getUsers and getStudents methods and thi is overhead, so seems that there is no solution to make code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict your types to something other than Any, you can create a parameterized DataType:

```
data class Datatype<T> {
    companion object {
        val USERS = Datatype<User>
        val STUDENTS = Datatype<Student>
        ...
...
```

And send that to your generic function:

```
fun <T> getData(datatype: Datatype<T>): List<T>? {
    return when(datatype) {
        Datatype.USERS -> getUsers() as List<T>
        Datatype.STUDENTS -> getStudents() as List<T>
        else -> null
    }
}
```