# Pass a type as parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, widget

I have this function which deletes all elements of a type in a layout.

```
fun DeleteAllOfTypeInLayout(t:TYPE){
    for(child in layout.children){
        if(child is t)
            layout.removeView(child)
    }
}
```

How can have this TYPE parameter?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588178/how-to-pass-a-type-to-generic-method-in-kotlin

Comment: Yes, i saw it.  Hum, actually, i did not understood the answers... I wasn't sure it as the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Kotlin's Reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters)

```
inline fun <reified T> DeleteAllOfTypeInLayout() {
    for (child in layout.children) {
        if (child is T)
            layout.removeView(child)
    }
}

// DeleteAllOfTypeInLayout<TextView>()
```