# Is it possible to use a KType as a generic type parameter argument?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
val type = typeOf<Int>()
val list = arrayListOf<**type**>()
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `typeOf` returns a `KType` - runtime types are objects in-memory and are unrelated to generic type arguments and type constraints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a type to generic method in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588178/how-to-pass-a-type-to-generic-method-in-kotlin)