# Generics in Kotlin Methods

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

Hey I want to make a function like that:

```kotlin
fun foo(name: String): Foo<out Test,  String> {
        return foo2(TestImpl::class.java)
}

fun <T, K> foo2(clazz: Class<T>): Foo<T, K>
```

But how can I do this without the "out Test" because when I use this in the Methods where I have to give an instance of Test in the Interface my IDE says the parameter is "Nothing" so I cant invoke the Method.

Is there anyone who know what I want to do and can help me to find a solution?

Thanks

Comment: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588178/how-to-pass-a-type-to-generic-method-in-kotlin) .

Comment: could you be more specific about how your are accessing and what is breaking

Comment: hmm `fun foo(name: String): Foo<out Test,  String> = foo2<TestImpl, String>()` and `inline fun <reified T, K> foo2(): Foo<T, K> = Foo()` is the best I could come up with, I think the `out` is unavoidable

Answer (score 0):

If this is the proper signature for `foo2` (it may not be, depending on what `Foo` looks like), then

```
foo2(TestImpl::class.java)
```

has type

```
Foo<TestImpl, WhateverYouWantHere>
```

which is not a subtype of

```
Foo<Test, WhateverYouWantHere>
```

unless `Foo` has `out` for the first parameter in its definition, but then you wouldn't have any "Methods where I have to give an instance of Test in the Interface".

And the only way to get *that* is to pass `Test::class.java` instead.